# link to an url page from a marker in a map javascript

Tags: javascript, leaflet, markers, url-link

I am writing a blog with html, php and javascript about my travels.
I have a classical menu in which I choose a country. That links me to a new page with an article about this country.

I would like to change it like this :
I have a map with a marker for each country I went to. I would like to click on the marker to move to the corresponding page.

In my javascript I have my map and my markers :

```
var map = L.map('mapid').setView([25, 22], defaut_zoom);
var carte="http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"

L.tileLayer(carte, {
    attribution:'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, DeLorme, NAVTEQ, USGS, Intermap, iPC, NRCAN, Esri Japan, METI, Esri China (Hong Kong), Esri (Thailand), TomTom, 2012'}).addTo(map);      
    var finlande = L.marker([60.1698,24.93837],{icon: satIcon}).addTo(map);
    var pouce = L.marker([47.50075,9.742309999999975]).addTo(map);

    //I tried to use an EventListener :

    finlande.addEventListener('click',function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("lien");
    });
})
```

it links to my php file :

```
<img id=lien><a href="finlande.html">
```

But it does not work. I have some basics in javascript but I have to admit that I get confused with what I can do in js and what I should do in html or php.
Thank you in advance for help !

Comment: Why is this tagged as google-maps when you are using leaflet?

Comment: Your event handler isn't actually _doing_ anything. Sure, you're grabbing an element, but you don't take any action on it or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bienvenue sur SO!

The low level [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method is for [Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).

Leaflet [`L.marker`](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker) factory (and the like) return a JavaScript *object*, which internally manage the Element that is displayed on the page.

Leaflet provides you with its [own mechanism](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#evented) to listen to events on those objects, but the API is similar to the low level one (or actually, similar to other libraries like jQuery):

```js
var map = L.map("map").setView([48.85, 2.35], 12);

var marker = L.marker([48.85, 2.35]).addTo(map);

marker.on('click', function(leafletEvent) {
  alert(leafletEvent.latlng);
});

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 200px"></div>
```

See also that question on GIS Stack Exchange: [Add an event listener on a Marker in Leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172508/add-an-event-listener-on-a-marker-in-leaflet)

Then if you want the user to be redirected to some page when he/she clicks on the marker, instead of the above `alert` example, simply use `window.location = "finlande.html"` for example, like shown in @d324223's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add some action in your event listener, in example to go to url:

```
finlande.addEventListener('click',function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location = "finlande.html"; 
});
```

Comment: Thank you ! I used the solution of ghybs and I added your window.location advice :)